# Not able to plot pcd file from PCDLoader in 3js

Tags: three.js, point-clouds, lidar

I am trying to plot pcd file following the example mentioned [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_pcd). WIth the given pcd I am able to plot but the pcd I have I am not able to plot. I cross checked the format and there were no errors as well in browser. Here is my [pcd file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tkf-CC1fW1ncT41IxunM445BMkjr2WGf). I am not getting whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your PCD file on my computer and it renders find. However, just replacing the `PCD` file in the mentioned example won't work since the spatial distribution of the data set is totally different. Hence you need a different camera and control setting. You should be able to see the point cloud with the following basic code:

```js
var camera, container, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 15, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 700;

    scene.add( camera );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var loader = new THREE.PCDLoader();
    loader.load( './models/pcd/binary/test.pcd', function ( points ) {

        points.material.size = 5;

        scene.add( points );

    } );
        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Comment: I can see the points now. Can you please tell me on what basis shall I decide the camera and control setting. Thanks.

Comment: It's best when you set a breakpoint in the callback handler of `PCDLoader.load()` and then inspect the parsed `points` object. The geometry data (to be more precise the `position` attribute and the corresponding bounding box) will provide you information about the size and position of the geometry. An other more advanced and automated approach is to derive optimal camera properties from the object's bounding box like certain viewer apps. The code can look like so: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/68e8bfbf0087e7778c9a3e317156564efbdde0e6/src/viewer.js#L218-L248

Comment: thank you very much.. One last help can you please suggest me where i can learn 3js basics, and the 3d related terminologies ?

Comment: One of the collaborators is working on a brand new [book](https://discoverthreejs.com/book/contents/). You will also find many resources in the official [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-bookshelf/2468) and the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html).